# How do I get SQL out of knex scripts?

Tags: sql, knex.js

I have a set of scripts that build a database using knex. What is the minimum effort possible to build this database or get the SQL for building it? I do not have Node.js set up for myself and I am new to both Node.js and Knex, but I do know SQL.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the minimum effort possible to build this database or get the
>   SQL for building it?

Your 2 options are either:

1. Install Node on your local machine (very simple [see: link](http://nodejs.org)), and run the scripts against a local database (may or may not be simple depending on the amount of environment setup required.). Then you can use your DB to dump the table creation SQL if you want to build the tables on a different database.
2. Review the Knex scripts and reverse engineer them. The Knex table creation functions are not complicated to understand, and you can reference the Knex API [here](http://knexjs.org).

I would recommend giving #1 a try, and if it takes you more than an hour or 2, then just do #2, unless there are 50-ish or more tables, then work your way through #1 anyway.

PS: If you run the Knex scripts, you can also turn on debugging in the knex connection configuration, and the SQLs being executed will be output to the console.

Comment: Excuse me for the stupid question, but once I have the Node set up on my computer, how do I run the scripts against local database? It installed and when I run the shortcut added to my Start Menu, it just shows something console-like. I do have a local Postgres instance (which is perfect as I know they actually use Postgres as well).

Comment: You will need to open and use a (dos) command window.  It'll be easiest if node is in your executable path, and your have the scripts in the current directory. If so you can run `node script-name.js`, otherwise you must add the fully qualified pathname to both like: `<node-path>/node <script-path>/script-name.js`. (see also https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/cli.html )

Also the knex configuration needs to be set for the database. See: http://knexjs.org/#Installation The db config directions are right after the knex install section (you need to do that too if you haven't).